# Create content that is related to blocks

Tags: views, blocks

I need you to help me with a type of content.

I want to create a content that when you enter to publish it has related or referenced blocks created in the different views. Thus the administrator assigns the different blocks to a basic page.

[image]

Within my content, I refer to the block created with that structure. The format of the block is to display grid-type content.

I tried doing it by adding a field type in this way

[image]

[image]

> I hope it gets better understood now. thank you very much

Comment: Drupal version?

Comment: is for Drupal 8.
Is this possible to do?

Comment: Not sure if  I understand your question correctly. You want when people go to `/node/add/article` to be able to reference blocks created in Views?

Comment: For example, within the "Basic Page" content, I relate the blocks created from Views within the content. I call the blocks (example) companies and that block will have its different structure, so it can call other blocks of other views (produstos) that will have a different structure.

Comment: @lcaraves it would be best if you describe what your end goal is, without making assumptions about the structure, because that might not be the way to go. Maybe you're after showing Views block with arguments that control what to show inside the block, depending on the page they are on. Are your companies and produstos related? So when you create a Basic Page, and select a Company when creating the page, you see a block listing that company's products? Or something similar?

Comment: @lcaraves you didn't add much to explain your end goal. It seems you're trying to have an Entity reference field to a block that is created by Views. Are all the different blocks created before the content? So you don't need them created automatically? If the Views blocks have arguments to create to the node they are displayed on, you don't need the reference field, arguments can take care of some contextual values. In your screenshots it seems the View you created doesn't have a block display, can you confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it this way

[image]

Inside my Content "Basic Page"

in Display, I see the blocks created with their styles. And then in my content it is visualized how they are made in the block view.

[image]

In "manage Display" I can move the created field, giving different locations without modifying the block structure. And remove or add block in my content.

I hope that it serves you thanks.